# How can I use script to create a typescript of my terminal session?

Tags: shell, gcc, terminal

I should compile and run my file and record it with script in a typescript. But when I try it I get unexpected results in the file. Am I doing something wrong?

```
$ script
Script started, file is typescript
developer@developer-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/kth/os/smallshell/oslab$ gcc -Wall -O4 -ansi -pedantic miniShell.c
developer@developer-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/kth/os/smallshell/oslab$ exit
exit
Script done, file is typescript
developer@developer-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/kth/os/smallshell/oslab$ more typescript 
Script started on Mon 18 May 2015 06:38:38 CEST
developer@de
-ansi -pedantic miniShell.cp/kth/os/smallshell/oslab$ gcc -Wall -O4  
developer@de
veloper-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/kth/os/smallshell/oslab$ exit
exit

Script done on Mon 18 May 2015 06:38:58 CEST
developer@developer-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/kth/os/smallshell/oslab$
```

Comment: Try looking at it in `less` or an editor that is smarter about control characters. `script` writes a very exacting rendition of the session and things that aren't expecting control characters will not display it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`script` records *all* characters sent to your terminal.  That includes all kinds of terminal control sequences (such as cursor movement, colors, etc).

By default, `less` (and other pages) do not work well with these control characters.  Use the [`-R` option of `less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less) to allow the program to render the file as it was originally sent.  There are some limitations, since even this presumes that the file is not generated in fullscreen mode.  To handle *that*, your best choice is to slowly `cat` the file to a terminal with the *same size* as that on which the file was generated.  For that, I use a program [`slowcat`](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:slowcat).  Others use a `-t` option to [`script`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) which records timing information (but that is not available on all versions of `script` — essentially, Linux-specific).

Alternatively, you can use a program or script to remove these control sequences, and get something comparable (without video highlights and colors) to that which `less -R` would show.  Some discussion of how to do this is found in *[Can I programmatically “burn in” ANSI control codes to a file using unix utils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269278/can-i-programmatically-burn-in-ansi-control-codes-to-a-file-using-unix-utils/28334291#28334291)*.