# UNIX script command includes gibberish in export

Tags: windows, unix, text

I'm trying you use the `script` command simply to save some prompts and output.

On unix, the output looks correct.

```
Script started on Sun 11 Sep 2016 06:34:13 PM EDT
[name@serv ~]$ mkdir myrepos
[name@serv ~]$ cd myrepos
[name@serv myrepos]$ svnadmin create testrepo
[name@serv myrepos]$ cd ../project
```

however, when I FTP the file to windows, I get:

```
Script started on Sun 11 Sep 2016 06:34:13 PM EDT
]0;name@serv:~[?h[name@serv ~]$ svn[K[K[Kmkdir myre[K[Krepos
]0;name@serv:~[name@serv ~]$ cd myrepos
]0;name@serv:~/myrepos[name@serv myrepos]$ svnadmin create testrepo[K[K[K[
```

Notepad shows the above with Ks and special character missing rectangles.
Notepad++ shows me not only the Ks, but random `ESC`, `BEL`, and  `BS` blocks.

I was hoping it was as simple as:

```
unix2dos original.txt windows.txt
```

but this tells me `unix2dos: problems converting file windows.txt`

Running `iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 in.txt > out.txt` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets) didn't help me either. At this point, I'm lost.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The problem is that `script` records everything that's written to the terminal. If you type <backspace> while entering a command, you'll see the final line, but the file will record the control sequences used to move the cursor back and forth. It will also record any control sequences used for highlighting in your shell prompt. You can see this on the Unix side with `cat -A` or `cat -v`.

Comment: Suggestion: Temporarily set your prompt to something simple, and be careful when typing any commands you want to record. Or copy-and-paste the output from your terminal rather than using `script`, so you only get what appears on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that simple, but you can transform the file on the Unix side, e.g., using `sed`.  `unix2dos` and `iconv` solve a different problem than this, and cannot help with it.

There are several related answers, but I prefer the script which I wrote to answer [Can I programmatically “burn in” ANSI control codes to a file using unix utils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269278/can-i-programmatically-burn-in-ansi-control-codes-to-a-file-using-unix-utils/28334291#28334291).

The script is described briefly on [one of my webpages](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:script2log), with some examples.  It can be downloaded from that page, in a [gzip'd tarfile](http://invisible-island.net/datafiles/release/misc-scripts.tar.gz).

Starting with the tarball...

```
tar xf misc-scripts.tar.gz
mv misc-scripts-2*/script2log .
rm -rf misc-scripts-2*
```

(unless you are interested in the other scripts: the tarball is simply a snapshot with files up to a given date which expands to a directory named with that date).

To use it, put `script2log` in your path, or just run it:

```
./script2log typescript >plaintext.log
```

or

```
./script2log -o plaintext.log typescript
```

Comment: both answers are great and a good place to start digging into the root cause .

Comment: So i'm still learning as to what exactly is going on, but I'm definitely getting the idea.  Wanting to use your fancy script though, (as sed didn't work completely), can I get a eli5 on how to use script2log ?  Thanks.

Comment: While definitely far cleaner then I was using, I have scenario where the script deleted more then it should.  Would you be interested in the files to help improve the script?

Comment: sure - I can take a look :-)