# How to strip the ANSI escape codes from a text file?

Tags: regex, terraform, notepad++, ansi-escape

I am working on VSCode 1.51 (at this point in time the most recent version), and while running `terraform plan ..` from the integrated PowerShell (5.1 on this workstation) I noticed that if I was redirecting the output to a text file, either via the operator (`.. > .\a.txt`) or via the Tee-Object (`.. | Tee-Object -FilePath .\a.txt`) the produced output file was mangled by [ASCII escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code); specifically by Control Sequence Introducer (CSI) sequences, such as ESC[1m.
In the output files I have seen so far I observed only the following 6 sequences:

```
- ESC[0m
- ESC[1m
- ESC[4m
- ESC[31m
- ESC[32m
- ESC[33m
```

I am using Notepad++ 7.8.7 to read the files, how do I replace the above sequences with a single space character (' ')?

**Update**

Obviously, if it could be possible to remove the ASCII escape sequences from the `terraform plan` output it would be even better.

Comment: To whoever has flagged this question as clone of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269278/can-i-programmatically-burn-in-ansi-control-codes-to-a-file-using-unix-utils, those are two completely unrelated questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question as you asked it, but I just wanted to note that `terraform plan` has a `-no-color` option which will disable the control codes and just emit plain text at the source, avoiding the need to strip the codes out later.

Comment: Thank you @martin-atkins, that's a great suggestion, I may leverage that parameter when I need to investigate the terraform plan output on a text file.

Comment: I have marked this as the best answer. I have updated the question, to state that removing the root cause would be a more desirable outcome.

Answer (score 8):

As per the documentation of Notepad++ 7.8.7:

> Notepad++ regular expressions use the Boost regular expression library v1.70, which is based on PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) syntax, only departing from it in very minor ways.

I replaced the escape sequences directly in Notepad++, using the following regular expression to find the strings to replace:

```
\e\[(.*?)m
```

and replacing them with a single space character (' ' without the quotes inside the **Replace with:** field on the Notepad++ Replace dialog).
In details:

- `\e` matches the escape character,
- `\[` matches the opening square bracket,
- `\e\[` matches therefore the Control Sequence Introducer ("ESC ["),
- `(.*?)m` matches any string until the first occurrence of the character 'm'.