# How to address ANSI Escape Sequences in sed?

Tags: sed, escaping, ansi-escape

A file with an ASCII-art logo is bloated with 'rgb-black foreground space characters'. Vim shows them as

```
^[[38;2;0;0;0m ^[[0m
```

Can I get sed to substitute this with 'regular' space characters, and if so, how?

```
sed -i 's/\\033\[38;2;0;0;0m \\033\[0m/ /g' $FILE
```

doesn't do the job on Bash V5.2.15 (up-to-date Debian12 x86_64)

Comment: see: https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream

Comment: This answers your question: [Can I programmatically "burn in" ANSI control codes to a file using unix utils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269278/can-i-programmatically-burn-in-ansi-control-codes-to-a-file-using-unix-utils) -- one of several duplicates

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i 's/Ctrl-VEsc\[38;2;0;0;0m Ctrl-VEsc\[0m/ /g' "$FILE"
```

The escape character is not special to sed, and can be typed directly into a single-quoted string from the bash commandline as shown above. <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> should be replaced by whatever `stty -a` shows is assigned as `lnext`.

To avoid using literal escape characters (which probably won't survive cut&paste, etc), bash's `$''` notation could be used with some doubling of backslashes:

```
sed -i $'s/\033\\[38;2;0;0;0m \033\\[0m/ /g' $FILE
```

or moving them outside:

```
sed -i $'s/\033''\[38;2;0;0;0m '$'\033''\[0m/ /g' $FILE
```

Standard `sed` does not understand escape (or hex) sequences like `\033`, although GNU sed does:

```
sed -i 's/\033\[38;2;0;0;0m \033\[0m/ /g' $FILE
```